# Loop not completing it's task

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to create a Sudoku puzzle so I came up with this python code below which is meant to print a dictionary whose keys are from the Btns list, but when run the code doesn't complete the task and also does not give any error message. I need help deciphering what the problem might be and how to fix it.

```
    from random import randint

    Btns = ['A11', 'A12', 'A13', 'A21', 'A22', 'A23', 'A31', 'A32', 'A33',
            'B14', 'B15', 'B16', 'B24', 'B25', 'B26', 'B34', 'B35', 'B36',
            'C17', 'C18', 'C19', 'C27', 'C28', 'C29', 'C37', 'C38', 'C39',
            'D41', 'D42', 'D43', 'D51', 'D52', 'D53', 'D61', 'D62', 'D63',
            'E44', 'E45', 'E46', 'E54', 'E55', 'E56', 'E64', 'E65', 'E66',
            'F47', 'F48', 'F49', 'F57', 'F58', 'F59', 'F67', 'F68', 'F69',
            'G71', 'G72', 'G73', 'G81', 'G82', 'G83', 'G91', 'G92', 'G93',
            'H74', 'H75', 'H76', 'H84', 'H85', 'H86', 'H94', 'H95', 'H96',
            'I77', 'I78', 'I79', 'I87', 'I88', 'I89', 'I97', 'I98', 'I99']
    H1 = list(range(1,10))
    H2 = list(range(1,10))
    H3 = list(range(1,10))
    H4 = list(range(1,10))
    H5 = list(range(1,10))
    H6 = list(range(1,10))
    H7 = list(range(1,10))
    H8 = list(range(1,10))
    H9 = list(range(1,10))
    V1 = list(range(1,10))
    V2 = list(range(1,10))
    V3 = list(range(1,10))
    V4 = list(range(1,10))
    V5 = list(range(1,10))
    V6 = list(range(1,10))
    V7 = list(range(1,10))
    V8 = list(range(1,10))
    V9 = list(range(1,10))
    A = list(range(1,10))
    B = list(range(1,10))
    C = list(range(1,10))
    D = list(range(1,10))
    E = list(range(1,10))
    F = list(range(1,10))
    G = list(range(1,10))
    H = list(range(1,10))
    I = list(range(1,10))

    the_game = {}

    #iterating through Btns
    for btns in Btns:
            first = btns[0]
            second = btns[1]
            third = btns[2]
            r = randint(1, 9)

            #Assigning an array to first_list
            if first == 'A':
                    first_list = A
            elif first == 'B':
                    first_list = B
            elif first == 'C':
                    first_list = C
            elif first == 'D':
                    first_list = D
            elif first == 'E':
                    first_list = E
            elif first == 'F':
                    first_list = F
            elif first == 'G':
                    first_list = G
            elif first == 'H':
                    first_list = H
            else:
                    first_list = I

            #Assigning an array to second_list
            if second == '1':
                    second_list = H1
            elif second == '2':
                    second_list = H2
            elif second == '3':
                    second_list = H3
            elif second == '4':
                    second_list = H4
            elif second == '5':
                    second_list = H5
            elif second == '6':
                    second_list = H6
            elif second == '7':
                    second_list = H7
            elif second == '8':
                    second_list = H8
            else:
                    second_list = H9

            #Assigning an array to third_list
            if third == '1':
                    third_list = V1
            elif third == '2':
                    third_list = V2
            elif third == '3':
                    third_list = V3
            elif third == '4':
                    third_list = V4
            elif third == '5':
                    third_list = V5
            elif third == '6':
                    third_list = V6
            elif third == '7':
                    third_list = V7
            elif third == '8':
                    third_list = V8
            else:
                    third_list = V9

            #Making sure r is contained in the three lists
            while (r not in first_list) or (r not in second_list) or (r not in third_list):
                    r = randint(1, 9)

            print(r)
            print(first_list)
            print(second_list)
            print(third_list)
            the_game[btns] = r # Adding r to the dictionary

            #Removing r from the three lists
            first_list.remove(r)
            second_list.remove(r)
            third_list.remove(r)
    print(the_game)
```

Comment: Think hard if you need this much duplication with so many instance variables. You can probably accomplish this with a single array.

Comment: @Ekene, welcome to Stack Overflow! You have an "infinite loop" in your code. Work is to find out if it is on the external "for" or on the internal "while" loop. I suggest you scale down your attempt. First, do it for a 9 elements Btns array; then do it for the original 81 elements. This is Dijkstra's divide-&-conquer approach at work. Hope it helps. Nice coding!

Answer (score 0):

There can be a scenario when none of the numbers from 1 to 9 are present in all the lists:

A11 : 1, A12 : 2, A13 : 3, A21 : 4, A22 : 5, A23 : 6, A31 : 7, A32 : 8, A33 : 9

B15 : 6, B25: 2, B35 : 1

D51 : 3, D52 : 4, D53 : 5

E44 : 7, E45 : 8, E46 : 9

Now what can be filled in E55? Nothing possible and while loop will be stuck.